# C# parameterless initialization class property that sets field parameter in ctor

Tags: c#, .net, constructor, properties, field

I am currently solving some issue that I have been solving at least five times.
Lets have a class like this. This is working solution, but I have to initialize class through parameter in ctor.

```
public class ArrayBenchmark
{
    private readonly int[] _numbers;

    public ArrayBenchmark(uint elementCount)
    {
        _numbers = Enumerable
            .Range(0, (int)elementCount)
            .Select(_ => new Random().Next(-9, 10))
            .ToArray();
    }
```

If I want to use it with parameterless way, it does not work, because the ctor has some priority, so the field is always initialized with the default property value. Code example below.

```
public class ArrayBenchmark
{
    private readonly int[] _numbers;

    public uint ElementCount { get; init; } = 1;

    public ArrayBenchmark()
    {
        _numbers = Enumerable
            .Range(0, (int)ElementCount)
            .Select(_ => new Random().Next(-9, 10))
            .ToArray();
    }
```

```
var benchmarkWith10Elements = new ArrayBenchmark { ElementCount = 10 };
benchmarkWith10Elements.CalculateAllComplexities();
```

So, is there some way how to fill field parameter from property through parameterless class initialization?
Thanks guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whaty you want is impossible because the parameterless constructor is called before you initialize the property. This ...

```
var benchmarkWith10Elements = new ArrayBenchmark { ElementCount = 10 };
```

is the same code as (syntactic sugar for) ...

```
var benchmarkWith10Elements = new ArrayBenchmark(); // here ElementCount is 1
benchmarkWith10Elements.ElementCount = 10;
```

So you need a constructor with an `ElementCount` parameter:

```
public ArrayBenchmark(uint elementCount)
{
    ElementCount = elementCount;
    _numbers = Enumerable
        .Range(0, (int)ElementCount)
        .Select(_ => new Random().Next(-9, 10))
        .ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the code I can see that with *parameterless class initialization* you mean the usage of [object initializers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers). So for your use case, no you cannot use object initializers when you have initialization logic dependent on public properties in the constructor.

The reason for this is very simple. Object initializers are just some syntactic sugar provided for us. When you have a look at the lowered C# using a tool like e.g. [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io) we can immediately see this.

Here the "normal" C# code:

```cs
namespace MyProgram;
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public class ArrayBenchmark
    {
        private readonly int[] _numbers;
        public uint ElementCount { get; init; } = 3;

        public ArrayBenchmark()
        {
            _numbers = Enumerable
                .Range(0, (int)ElementCount)
                .Select(_ => new Random().Next(-9, 10))
                .ToArray();
        }
    }
    
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var benchmarkWith10Elements = new ArrayBenchmark { ElementCount = 10 };
    }
}
```

Then the equivalent lowered C# will look like the following. I am only showing the `Main()` method since this shows the relevant part. Visit [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io) and paste the normal C# code in to see the complete class in lowered C#.

```cs
        [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.NullableContext(1)]
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ArrayBenchmark arrayBenchmark = new ArrayBenchmark();
            arrayBenchmark.ElementCount = 10u;
            ArrayBenchmark arrayBenchmark2 = arrayBenchmark;
        }
```

Here we can see that the object initializer is turned into a normal constructor invocation and then a property assignment. Hence, the logic in the constructor will already have run before the property gets the new value and the default value is being used.

So I would recommend to stick with the constructor invocation for your use case. In theory you could of course also have some logic in the setter, but then you unnecessarily create two arrays and setters should be quick operations, which this might not be since `ElementCount` could be rather large. So while theoretically possible it's not a good idea.